# How do you prevent CanCan authorizing access when it's passed just a class object (no instance)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

When CanCan's `load_and_authorize_resource` cannot find an instance of an object it falls back to authorizing against the object's class itself.

Copying from the [CanCan wiki](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions#authorize_resource):

> Adding authorize_resource will install a before_action callback that calls authorize!, passing the resource instance variable if it exists. If the instance variable isn't set (such as in the index action) it will pass in the class name. For example, if we have a ProductsController it will do this before each action.
>
> ```
> authorize!(params[:action].to_sym, @product || Product)
> ```

And by default, CanCan seems to grant behaviour to an object class. First off I find this behaviour terrifying. But leaving that aside I can't figure out what the syntax is to prevent access to the class.

In the scenario above where `@product` is nil, what do you put into the ability file to prevent cancan allowing access?

#### What is the syntax for setting permissions on the class (rather than actions on that class)?

If the syntax for setting normal permissions is:

```
can [:edit], Page do |page|
  page.author == user
end
```

Then what is the syntax for setting the permissions on the class itself:

```
# This doesn't work
can [:edit], Page do |page|
  false if !page
  page.author == user
end
```

But what does?

Answer (score 0):

Don't like "link answers", but it is the case.

From [CanCan wiki](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks#only-for-object-attributes)

```rb
# don't do this
can :update, Project do |project|
  user.admin? # this won't be called for Project.accessible_by(current_ability, :update)
end

# do this
can :update, Project if user.admin?
```

Comment: "What is the syntax for setting permissions on the class?" is a bolded question, but it's not what they want to know.

Comment: I've just updated the question to make it a little clearer

Answer (score 0):

Solution is simple: don't use `load_and_authorize_resource` and call `authorize!` yourself. Something like this:

```
def index
  authorize!(:index, Product)
  ...
end

def show
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  authorize!(:show, @product)
  ...
end
```

You have to type more, but on the other hand, no magic fallbacks.

Comment: This is the solution i've gone with but I've got a lot of different controllers. So I was looking for a solution that would let me lock down access in the ability file rather than updating each of the controllers individually